# How to deny outside post requests?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I would like in Liferay to allow only logged in users to do post requests, and at the same time deny other Post request sources, like from Postman, for example.

Comment: Could you please share with us what have you done this far?

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat that I am not familiar with Liferay itself, I can tell you that in a general Web application what you are asking is impossible.

Let's consider the problem in its simplest form:

1. A Web application makes POST requests to a server
2. The server should allow requests only from a logged-in user using the Web application

The server is stateless - that is, each request must be considered atomically.  There is no persistent connection and no state is preserved at the server.

So - let's consider what happens when the browser makes a POST:

1. An HTTP connection is opened to the server
2. The HTTP headers are sent, including any site cookies that have previously been set by the server, and special headers like the User Agent and referrer
3. The form data is posted to the server
4. The server processes the request and returns a response

How does the server know that the user is logged in?  In most cases, this is done by checking a cookie that is sent with the request and verifying that it is correct - cryptographically signed, for instance.

Now let's consider a Postman request.  Exactly what is the difference between a request submitted through Postman and one submitted through the browser?  **None**.  There is no difference.  It is trivially simple to examine and retrieve the cookies sent on a legitimate request from the browser, and include those headers in a faked Postman request.

Let's consider what you might do to prevent this.
 1. Set and verify extra cookies - won't work because we can still retrieve those cookies just like we did with the login session
 2. Encrypt the connection so the cookies can't be captured over the wire - won't work because I can capture the cookies from the browser
 3. Check the User Agent to ensure that it is sent by a browser - won't work because I can spoof the headers to any value I want
 4. Check the Referrer to ensure the request came from a valid page on my site (this is part of a Cross-Site Request Forgery mitigation) - won't work because I can always spoof the Referrer to any value I want 
 5. Add logic (JavaScript) into the page to compute some validity token - won't work because I can still read the JavaScript (it's client-side) and fake my own token

By the very nature of the Web system, this problem is insoluble.  Because you (the server/application writer) do not have complete control over both sides of the communication, it is **always** possible to spoof requests from the client. The best you can do is prevent arbitrary requests from arbitrary users who do not have valid credentials.  However, **any** request that includes the correct security tokens **must** be considered valid, whether it is generated from a browser/web page or crafted by hand or through some other application.  At best, you will needlessly complicate your application for no significant improvement in security.  You can prevent CSRF attacks and some other injection-type attacks, but because you as the client can **always** read whatever is sent from the server and can **always** craft your own requests, you can **always** provide a valid request.

Answer (score 0):

## Clarification

Can you please explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to disable guest access completely, even through "valid" referrers (a user actually submitting a form) or are you trying to prevent post requests coming from other referrers?

If you are just worried about referrer forgeries you can set the following property in your **portal-ext.properties** file.

```
auth.token.check.enabled = true
```

If you want to remove all permissions for the guest role you can simply go into the portal's control panel, go into Configuration and then into the permissions table.  Unchecked the entire row associated with guest.

That should do it. If you can't find those permissions post your exact Liferay version.